# Regex stop script error occur for long values

Tags: javascript, regex

First letter should be alpha/numeric and forward slash, every special characters are allowed except & and |

```
 new RegExp('^[\/A-Za-z0-9](([^\|\&]?[a-zA-Z0-9]?)*)$');
```

Above regex work for correct format and minimum characters e.g(**/abcd%***)

If i give long character e.g( **/abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd&** ),stop script error occurs in firefox. Please suggest some better regex for fix it

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2dkkuaa/)**

Comment: It would be better if you tell us what string(s) you are trying to match.

Comment: @SalmanA Just look at the fiddle or the post. He's trying to match with `/abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the capturing groups (brackets). Get rid of those and it's fine. Just make it as simple as you can!

> First letter should be alpha/numeric [or] forward slash

```
^[/A-Za-z0-9]
```

> every special characters are allowed except & and |

```
[^|&]+
```

(You don't need to escape `|` or `&`.)

Putting it together:

```
^[\/A-Za-z0-9][^|&]+$
```

Try it [here](http://regexr.com/3bulh).

Comment: Besides the capturing groups, there is also a potential catastrophic backtracking issue with the original regex.

Comment: Don't need to escape `/` either (inside first bracket).

Comment: Oh yeah! I always thought you did... :)